# Friends_interests/likes/etc return as blank from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been messing around with the graph API and have been able to access my own information just fine. However, when I attempt something like:

https://graph.facebook.com/999999/likes?access_token=xxx (where 999999 is a friend's ID)

I get a blank graph like so:

{
   "data": [

]
}

Keep in mind I'm doing this all manually for the time being. This is the URL I used to request permission from my profile:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://www.google.com&scope=email,read_stream,offline_access,user_likes,friends_likes

It all works hunky-dory and I get my access code, yet I still receive the blank graph. Suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried multiple friends? Your friends can configure what information third party applications can have access to, of theirs. For example I could limit applications that you use to not see anything about me, if we were friends.

Also you could check in account --> privacy --> settings --> applications and see if your application in fact has the permissions you think you granted it as a user.

-Kevin

Comment: When one creates a profile, it defaults to allow most information to be accessible through friends' apps. Mine aren't the most tech-savvy, so I doubt they changed this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with kevin.  You need to request [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) first to get at the info and you also need to be prepared that you will get a blank list.

I suggest that you use an already built api as it will save you a lot of time.  I've recently released one [here](http://fbapi.blogspot.com) that should get you going in no time at all.

The code looks like this:

```
Dim FB As New SessionInfo("[access_token]")
Dim Req = New Functions.Requests(FB)
Dim U = Req.GetUserInfo("[userid for friend]")
Response.Write(U.name)
```

Also you can get a list of friends by calling this

```
Dim FL = Req.GetFriends()
For Each F In FL
    Response.Write(F.name)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come to notice that even though an application can request (and be granted) certain permissions, e.g. to access Likes, it doesn't necessarily mean that an application will be able to access this information.

I'm not a 100% certain of this but there might be two instances where e.g. requesting a users Likes results in an empty data set even though the right permissions where requested and granted by the user:

1. The user has set custom permissions in his/her privacy settings
   not make public the information (e.g. Likes). Basically, customized
   permission settings overrule the granted permissions that an
   application requested.
2. The user is under 18. https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=214189648617074