# Facebook: All interests returning empty array (music, movies, etc)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the current user's favorite artists.

When I use the '/me/music' call (Using the 'music' link about a third of the way down this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) link I get a blank array, even though I have several favorite artsits.

If I authenticate myself using the PHP Facebook API I also get a blank array, even though I grant the 'user_likes' permission.

The only way I can pull this data is by changing my 'Interests' privacy setting to 'Everyone', which obviously makes having a specific permission for this data pointless.

I have checked the applications granted access on my profile and the app definitely has access to my likes.

A similar question was asked here: [Friends_interests/likes/etc return as blank from Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709521/friends-interests-likes-etc-return-as-blank-from-facebook-graph-api).

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks,
Matt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need the "user_interests" permission to read this information.

see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ for a list of possible permissions.

Comment: Thanks for this - totally my fault for thinking 'user_likes' incorporated music & such :)